# How can I vertically center a tag in flalign environment?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, tags, flalign

I am trying to use `flalign` environment, but the tag is not centered. I know that each entry after `\\` is taken as an independent equation in `flalign`, but is there a way to produce the same result below with a vertically centered tag?

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\newcommand {\scalelinespace} [1] {\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\graphpath}[3][L]{\zeta_{\substack{\vspace{0.5mm} \\ #1}}
    \left[\upsilon_{#2}, \thinspace \upsilon_{#3}\right]
                            }

\begin{flalign}
    &&  \graphpath[L]{l}{m}
        = &\left[\upsilon_{l}, \thinspace \upsilon_{x_{1}}, \thinspace \upsilon_{x_{2}}, \thinspace \cdots, \thinspace x_{n}, \thinspace \upsilon_{m} \right] & \hspace{1mm}
\\
    \text{where} && &\phantom{\left[\right.} l \neq x_{1} \neq x_{2} \cdots \neq n \neq m & \hspace{1mm}
    \notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use  `flalign` since you have at most one alignment point?

Comment: I want to use it because I want to save space. I could have used `align`, but if I had inserted 'where' using `intertext`, it would have taken a whole line on its own. What I want is to flush 'where' to the very left end and align two lines of the equations, but assign one tag for both of them (because one is just a condition to satisfy)

Comment: Semantically, I don't feel necessary to align both lines, so the condition could be inserted in the `\intertext`.

Comment: I understand fully that the alignment may not be really necessary, but some reviewers need to be spoon-fed everything, so I work as hard as I can to make the text as clear as it could get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose these two variants, which rely on the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`: it makes equations aligned at the left margin for equations inside the environment (works like  `subequations`)Inside I put an `aligned` with two columns, nested in an `equation` environment:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\newcommand {\scalelinespace} [1] {\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\graphpath}[3][L]{\zeta_{\mkern-1.5mu#1\strut}
\left[\upsilon_{#2}, \,\upsilon_{#3}\right]
                        }

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    && \graphpath[L]{l}{m}
        = &\left[\upsilon_{l}, \,\upsilon_{x_{1}}, \,\upsilon_{x_{2}}, \, \cdots, \, x_{n}, \,\upsilon_{m} \right] 
\\
    \text{where} && &\phantom{\left[\right.} l \neq x_{1} \neq x_{2} \cdots \neq n \neq m 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\begin{fleqn}
\vskip3ex
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    && &\graphpath[L]{l}{m}
=\left[\upsilon_{l}, \thinspace \upsilon_{x_{1}}, \,\upsilon_{x_{2}}, \,\cdots, \,  x_{n}, \, \upsilon_{m} \right] 
\\
    \text{where} && & l\neq x_{1}\neq x_{2}\cdots \neq n \neq m 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution! But I disagree with all my heart how the OP uses `\substack{\vspace{0.5mm} \\ #1}` and `\left[...\right]`. Also, writing consecutive `\neq`’s are questionable and could be very confusing… I’d prefer something like `where $l$, $x_1$, $x_2$, \dots, $n$, $m$ are distinct indices`.

Comment: @Ruixi Zhang: I confess I didn't look at this part of the code. I suppose it's to have a lower placement of the subscript when it's a capital letter. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Yes, Bernard is right. It just about lowering the subscript. Try to remove `\substack{\vspace{0.5mm} \\ #1}` and replace it with `#1` alone. It will look not yield a good appearance when using the letter 'L'

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: I propose another, simpler definition for `\graphicspath`, with a tighter horizontal spacing for the index. PLease see the updated code and the resulting screenshot. B.t.w., `\thinspace` is just `\,` (simpler to type).